# Using Boost.build to include a library

Tags: c++, boost-build, cgns

I am using boost.build to compile a c++ code which references a library, [CGNS](http://cgns.sourceforge.net/), but am having some difficulty with using boost.build to do so.  CGNS compiles to a library, with a folder for the platform, for example [path]/LINUX for the linux build.  I would like to include the library [path]/LINUX/libcgns.a in the build.  I would like this to be cross-platform, so that the LINUX directory is referenced for LINUX builds and the WIN directory is used for WIN builds (I believe there are platform conditionals for this).

I managed to include the library header files, but how do I go about the conditional include of the library?  My simple test Jamroot.jam, where main.cpp is just an example from the CGNS docs.

```
exe CGNSTest 
    : src/main.cpp 
    : <include>../Dependencies/cgnslib ;
```

Also, I would like to build in the CGNS library into my binary (static reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two references, http://www.highscore.de/cpp/boostbuild/, and http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/doc/userman.pdf, I created something that works, but it may not be the ideal.

```
lib cgns 
    : # sources 
    : # requirements
      <name>cgns 
        <target-os>linux:<search>../Dependencies/cgnslib/LINUX
        <target-os>windows:<search>../Dependencies/cgnslib/WIN32
    : # default-build
    : # usage-requirements
      <include>./../Dependencies/cgnslib ;
alias static_libraries : cgns : <link>static ;
exe CGNSTest 
    : src/main.cpp static_libraries 
    : <target-os>windows:<linkflags>/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD ;
```